# Access the newly element appended as the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi,

```
    <html>
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>ATC Master</title>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".datepicker").datepicker();

                    $('#data ul li:last div#totmw input:last').focus(function(){
                    $("#data ul").last().after('<li><div style="float: left;"><input type="text" size="10"/></div><div id="totmw"><br><input type="text" size="10" class="datepicker"/><input type="text" size="10" class="totalmw"/></div><div style="clear: both;"></div></li>');
                    //alert("sel");
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body id="body-content">
        <form method="post" action="postATCMaster.htm">
            <div id="data" style="float: left;">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div style="float: left;">
                            <input type="text" size="10"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="totmw" style="float: left;">
                            <input type="text" size="10" class="datepicker"/>
                            <input type="text" size="10" class="totalmw"/>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both;">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here, I am able to add a new li element but only when focus is on the last input of the div of id-totmw of the first li. But as a new li is appended, I want a further new li be added on focusing only on the last input field of the div of id-totmw of the newly appended li element. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are added dynamically, you need to use event delegation. Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method as follows

```
$('#data').on('focus','li:last div#totmw input:last',function(){
 $("#data ul").last().after('<li><div style="float: left;"><input type="text" size="10"/></div><div id="totmw"><br><input type="text" size="10" class="datepicker"/><input type="text" size="10" class="totalmw"/></div><div style="clear: both;"></div></li>');
 //alert("sel");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2gG6/4/)

*Side note:  seems like you're dynamically adding elements with id, which will create multiple elements with same id, which is invalid - try using class instead.*

*Also, try to avoid inline styles, which will avoid duplicate code and make the code much cleaner: [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)*

Comment: Why `.last().after()..` why not just `.append()` ?

Comment: Also, just `$('#data ul').on('focus','input:last' ...`

Comment: @abhitalks idk. i fixed the `bloker` issue. i don't have time to teach query and it's best practices. it's out of the scope of a simple answer. there's no need to spam comments, you can always edit your comment within 5 minutes...

Comment: Thanks TJ, it seemed to work. However, I also would want the CSS for the rest of the doc to be applied to the new element. How can I do that?

Comment: @abhiram [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/g2gG6/3/) you just have to append the same html… note that you're adding elements with id, which will create multiple elements with same id, which is invalid… try using `class` instead...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#data').on('focus', 'li:last div#totmw input:last', function () {
$("#data ul").last().after('<li><div style="float: left;"><input type="text" size="10"/></div><div id="totmw"><br><input type="text" size="10" class="datepicker"/><input type="text" size="10" class="totalmw"/></div><div style="clear: both;"></div></li>');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/K3j92/

Answer (score -1):

Use `$(this).last()` instead of `$("#data ul").last()`